# Created an AMI but when I launch a new instance with it, it doesn't have the volume amount I specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EBS-optimized AMI (via the AWS console) of size 15 TB. But when I launch a new instance with this AMI and do `df -h`, it doesn't show 15TB of volume.

In terms of how I created the AMI, I launched an EC2 instance with Amazon's EBS-optimized AMI, added 15 TB to the EBS volume, and then created an AMI while this instance was still running.

What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot of when I created the image:

[image]

Result of `df -h` when I launched a new instance with the AMI:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        3.9G   68K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  827M  6.9G  11% /
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have two EBS disks, 8GB is the root and 1.5TB is secondary, When Amazon takes AMI, they will store the machine image in your root Disk (if its EBS backed or in s3 incase of instance store) and use the same disk when you boot a new instance from it, so your secondary 1.5TB will not gets replicated, you can read more here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html). So try 1.5TB as root volume while taking AMI's.